# How to rename files using CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm currently trying to rename a multiple files using command prompt but I just can't get it work.

So this is what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to renames these files

```
file_aaa_001.jpeg
file_bbb_002.jpeg
file_ccc_003.jpeg
```

To the following files:

```
001.jpeg
002.jpeg
003.jpeg
```

I know this is super beginner level, but I would be great if could get some help.

Edit: the sequences "aaa"s are not necessarily the same three letters, it could be any number of random letters.
So to be more clear, I want to delete the letters from the begging to the second "_". Thank you

Comment: Do the `aaa` `bbb` sequences continue beyond `zzz`?

Comment: well actually, the sequence are pretty random, it could be "abs","dba" or anything. So to clarify, I just need the files to have the chars between the second "_"and beyond

Comment: Take a look at [Mooniker](https://github.com/iandioch/mooniker). It's a command-line utility my friend wrote to rename a specific pattern in multiple files. You'll need to compile it yourself to use it though (and I don't think it supports Regex).

Comment: @BrandonIbbotsonth thanks for sharing. I'll take a look!!

Comment: Are there always exactly two `_` in the file names? Could the first two parts `file` and `aaa`, etc. also contain numeric figures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you just need to takeout the prefix, use

```
ren "*.*" "/////////*.*"
```

If you want to be prudent and only take those prefixed with "file_", followed with three character and last dash before the sequence, and only those with jpeg extension

```
ren "file_???_*.jpeg" "/////////*.*"
```

As always, you want to backup the folder before running/modifying the commands.

Comment: Good to know. You can accept my answer with the tick, or maybe wait if someone comes along to offer better method/explanation.

Comment: @Martheen +1 I've never seen this method and I couldn't find anything with a bit of searching. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @aphoria I also found it in other question about rename in SO from one of dozens (unaccepted) answer. The answer also mentions they never actually found the legit documentation

Answer (score 0):

Supposing there are always exactly two `_` characters in each file name and there is at least one other character in between, you could use a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to split the file names:

```cmd
for /F "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B "*_*_*.jpeg"
') do (
    for /F "tokens=2* delims=_" %%I in ("%%~nF") do (
        rename "%%~F" "%%J%%~xF"
    )
)
```